# How to change a property of another control from a listbox item selection event?

Tags: wpf, coding-style, triggers, listbox, datatrigger

I have a listbox and a border wrapping a textbox. I want to be able to change the style of the border's background depending on if ANY item in the listbox is selected.

The reason is that I use code-behind to make sure that no item is selected in certain conditions, so when an item in the listbox IS selected I want to display that.

```
<Border x:Name="brdMyBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderBackground="Blue">
    <TextBox ... />
</Border>

<ListBox x:Name="lstMyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="listbox_selectionchanged" />
```

I realize that I could always set the background in the `SelectionChanged` event, but I'd rather use xaml triggers somehow instead. I'm not sure how to go about this. The only triggers allowed on the Border seem to be EventTrigger.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Style with DataTriggers

```
<Style x:Key="MyBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lstMyListBox, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Note that you have to set the default Background color in the Style, because otherwise the `Background` specified in the `<Border>` tag will always override the Triggered value.

Comment: This works except I can't set the `Value` to a `StaticResource` ... if I hard code it similar to your example, like Red or Blue, it works. But, if I attempt to use a StaticResource it fails.

Comment: @michael Yes, if you want to use a 2nd parameter in your binding you'll probably need a `MultiBinding`, which can pass multiple dynamic values to a `MultiConverter` and return True or False to the `DataTrigger`

Answer (score 0):

How about using `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SelectionChanged">`

Comment: EventTriggers seem to want storyboards, not sure how to go into that.

Comment: @michael: You can use them, just make a single frame animation.